# Find multiple instances of a cell value in a master table on separate sheet - excel

Tags: excel, vba

**Application** - Shipping Log

**Objective** - Return all box sizes associated with a product code from a master table and determine the carton the product is shipped in. (Some codes have multiple boxes, the largest volume is always the one the product is shipped in)

I have one sheet named "ProductData" This contains a table that is to be populated from a query of our database.

[ProductData-Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo7sU.jpg)

On a separate sheet, I would like to use a cell to enter the product code and have next to this the shipping carton code and the volume auto populate. The issue is, for a given product code, there are multiple carton codes so a simple VLOOKUP will not work as it only returns the first instance in the table. I need to be able to return all instances in the table for the product code entered and then identify the max volume associated with the carton.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the lookup table by Product, then Volume descending will return the first product with the greatest volume.
[image]